# WPF: Localize WPF Ribbon QAT context menu texts

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, ribbon

I'm playing with the .NET 4.0 WPF ribbon and am looking for a way to localize the Ribbon context menu strings. By default, right clicking the ribbon shows items like "Minimize the Ribbon". I'd like to localize these strings to for example display "Multifunktionsleiste verbergen".

How would I do that? Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (hopefully) complete extension to userxyz's solution:

```
        FieldInfo pi;

        pi = typeof(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonContextMenu).GetField("AddToQATText", (BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static));
        pi.SetValue(null, "RibbonContext_AddToQATText");
        pi = typeof(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonContextMenu).GetField("RemoveFromQATText", (BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static));
        pi.SetValue(null, "RibbonContext_RemoveFromQATText");
        pi = typeof(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonContextMenu).GetField("ShowQATAboveText", (BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static));
        pi.SetValue(null, "RibbonContext_ShowQATAboveText");
        pi = typeof(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonContextMenu).GetField("ShowQATBelowText", (BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static));
        pi.SetValue(null, "RibbonContext_ShowQATBelowText");
        pi = typeof(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonContextMenu).GetField("MaximizeTheRibbonText", (BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static));
        pi.SetValue(null, "RibbonContext_MaximizeTheRibbonText");
        pi = typeof(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonContextMenu).GetField("MinimizeTheRibbonText", (BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static));
        pi.SetValue(null, "RibbonContext_MinimizeTheRibbonText");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but it cannot be possible without recompling library from sources (If I am not correct it would be great to here from someone) as the ribbon library defines ResourcesManager

```
new ResourceManager("ExceptionStringTable", typeof(SR).Assembly);
```

If you are changing source those texts are stored in resources file called ExceptionStringTable.txt.

The identifiers for strings are:

- RibbonContextMenu_ShowQATAbove
- RibbonContextMenu_ShowQATBelow
- RibbonContextMenu_MaximizeTheRibbon
- RibbonContextMenu_MinimizeTheRibbon

Sources for library can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4). In RibbonControlsLibrary\Resources\ you can found the implementation of resources for Ribbon.

Comment: Well, that's a shame really, but it seems to be the only way.

Comment: Sorry, Mark's reply actually worked better and without recompiling the library...

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to replace the values by reflection:

```
  FieldInfo pi = typeof(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonContextMenu).GetField("AddToQATText", (BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static));
  pi.SetValue(null, "Localized text");
```

This code has to be executed before the first usage of the ribbon control (typically InitializeComponent of the main window)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest another one solution based on previously discussed:

```
var ribbonResourceManager = new RibbonResourceManager();

var translatorType = typeof(RibbonContextMenu)
    .Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.Windows.Controls.SR");
var resourceManagerField = translatorType.GetField("_resourceManager", 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
resourceManagerField.SetValue(null, ribbonResourceManager);
```

where `RibbonReourceManager` is inheritor of the basic ResourceManager with overridden GetString methods. And `RibbonResourceManager` should return all strings listed below:

- "RibbonQuickAccessToolBar_OverflowButtonToolTip"
- "QATKeyTipCharacters"
- "RibbonContextMenu_AddToQAT"
- "RibbonContextMenu_AddGalleryToQAT"
- "RibbonContextMenu_RemoveFromQAT"
- "RibbonContextMenu_ShowQATAbove"
- "RibbonContextMenu_ShowQATBelow"
- "RibbonContextMenu_MaximizeTheRibbon"
- "RibbonContextMenu_MinimizeTheRibbon"